# Как передавать данные из одного окна в другое?

Tags: jquery, javascript, jquery-form

Есть форма на первой странице, по нажатию по кнопке на странице открывается окно с таблицей, и при двойном нажатии на строке из таблицы данные должны попадать в поля формы.

Если форму и таблицу разместить на одной странице, то всё работает, но если вынести таблицу в другое окно, которое создаётся функцией, уже не работает.

Если я правильно понимаю, проблема с глобальностью функций, наверное.

Вот код:

Главная страница:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Untitled</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>

    <button type="button" onclick="NewWindow()">Банки</button>

<br /><br />
    Bank Name:

    <br />

    <textarea id='bank' cols=56 rows=6></textarea>

    Bank Adress:

    <br />

    <textarea id='bic' cols=56 rows=6></textarea>

    <script>

        var textarea_bank = document.getElementById('bank'),

            textarea_bic = document.getElementById('bic');

        function comm(){
            var tmp = new Array();    // два вспомогательных
                  var tmp2 = new Array();  // массива
                  get = new Array();

                  var url = location.search;    // строка GET запроса
                  if(url != '') {
                    tmp = (url.substr(1)).split('&');   // разделяем переменные
                    for(var i=0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
                      tmp2 = tmp[i].split('=');     // массив get будет содержать
                      get[tmp2[0]] = tmp2[1];       // пары ключ(имя переменной)->значение
                    }
                  }
                }

        function NewWindow() 
            {
             var textarea_bank = document.getElementById('bank').innerHTML,
             textarea_bic = document.getElementById('bic').innerHTML;

             myChildWin =  window.open("test.html?bank="+textarea_bank+"&bic="+textarea_bic, "_blank", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, top=100, left=100, width=600, height=600");
            }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Окно с таблицей:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">   <head>      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />       <title>test</title>         </head>     <body>      <table id="mySuperTBL">         <tr>
                <td><b>BankName</b>
                </td>
                <td><b>BIC</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id='1' ondblclick='comm(this)'>
                <td>Bank</td>
                <td>Adress</td>         </tr>   </table>        </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: Может, использование cookie поможет в данной ситуации.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так: http://greenjs.ru/paste/Z1RumvPmu

```
var w = window.open();
w.document.write('Hello');
w.message = function(data) {
    alert(data); //обрабатываем в главном окне
};
//вызов в дочернем окне
message('Данные'); //передаем данные
```

Answer (score 1):

Запаковываете данные в URL при создании окна:

```
function NewWindow() 
{
 var textarea_bank = document.getElementById('bank').innerHTML,
 textarea_bic = document.getElementById('bic').innerHTML;

 myChildWin =  window.open("test.html?bank="+textarea_bank+"&bic="+textarea_bic, "_blank", "toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, top=100, left=100, width=600, height=600");
}
```

В новом окне по двойному клику разбираете пришедшую строку:

```
function comm(){
var tmp = new Array();    // два вспомогательных
      var tmp2 = new Array();  // массива
      get = new Array();

      var url = location.search;    // строка GET запроса
      if(url != '') {
        tmp = (url.substr(1)).split('&');   // разделяем переменные
        for(var i=0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
          tmp2 = tmp[i].split('=');     // массив get будет содержать
          get[tmp2[0]] = tmp2[1];       // пары ключ(имя переменной)->значение
        }
      }
    }
```

`get[bank] - данные из textarea "bank"
get[bic] - данные из textarea "bic"`

Comment: Спасибо, я сделал как вы написали, но по прежнему не работает. Обновил первое сообщение, там всё сделано, как вы написали, или может быть я что-то неправильно понял?

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте!
Когда я сам изучал HTML 3.2/4.0 и JS 1.4/1.5, то сам сталкивался с чем-то подобным.
Тогда, если не ошибаюсь, была реализация через "_parent" или что-то вроде этого. Ещё, есть свойство, вроде называется "referer", то есть обратиться к инициатору события.